# How to configure nutch 1.4 with hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

When I am firing this command

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -put url/urls_test url/urls_test
```

URLs are getting up correctly.

But below command is showing error

```
./bin/nutch crawl url/urls_test -dir cr_demo -depth 1
```

ERROR

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
```

Comment: can you paste logs from the logfile?

Answer (score 0):

The error which u hav pasted comes if NUTCH_CONF_DIR and NUTCH_HOME are not exported or pointed to wrong location.

See this http://www.rui-yang.com/develop/build-nutch-1-4-cluster-with-hadoop/ for detailed steps for using nutch 1.4 with hadoop 0.20